# This version of firebase_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build an apk to update my app on the android app store.   It is worth noting here that every plugin version that I use is absolutely identical to the version that is already on the store, and so has already previously built an apk with no issues at all.

```
[   +1 ms]          *********************************************************
[        ] WARNING: This version of firebase_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
[   +1 ms]          See https ://goo.gl /CP92wY for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
[   +1 ms]          This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
[        ]          *********************************************************
[        ] 355 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 339 up-to-date
[ +469 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 65.3s)
[   +7 ms] "flutter apk" took 118,030ms.
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I have done a lot of reading about this issue and so far nothing seems to work to resolve this, but the information that seems relevant from other posts is:

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
  firebase_admob: 0.5.5
  screen: 0.0.5
  image_picker: 0.6.1
  firebase_auth: 0.11.1+7
  shared_preferences: 0.4.3
  rflutter_alert: 1.0.2
  url_launcher: 5.0.3
  in_app_purchase: 0.2.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: 0.4.0+4
  app_review: 1.0.0
  auto_orientation: 1.0.4
  vibration: 1.2.1
```

root level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

app folder build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "my.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

Can't work out why this is happening, and there is not much info in the error message to go on.   Has anyone come across these androidx errors before?

Comment: use ` firebase_auth: 0.7.0` instead of your version and see if it helps

Comment: Hi @P4yam, thank you for the reply.   I set firebase_auth to 0.7.0, which meant I then had to set firebase_core down to 0.2.5+1, which then meant that firebase_database was too high, so through trial and error version by version I got it down to 1.1.0+1 which then meant that firebase_storage was too high.  Trial and error again, down to 1.1.0+1.

After all that, ran a flutter clean and attempted another "flutter build apk --release -v":

Comment: After all that I got:  This version of google_maps_flutter will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.

Comment: So I have been trying to find that document that says exactly what versions are supported by AndroidX, but for some reason it doesn't appear to exist any more even though I was reading it 12 hours ago.  

So I tried migrating project to androidx again, even though it already is an androidx project and I got an error saying starting gradle daemon failed.

So I set the gradle properties to say org.gradle.jvmargs=Xmx1024m instead of Xmx1536m and tried again, migrated successfully this time.

So then I tried to build apk again, same error regarding maps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by `firebase_auth` that has dependencies that uses [AndroidX](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/androidx-migration). The migration to AndroidX for Flutter's Android builds has been done way back. Following the migration guide to AndroidX should solve the issue. Alternatively, creating a new Flutter project uses AndroidX by default.